# Explain $\langle \emptyset \rangle=\{1\},\langle 1 \rangle=\{1\}. H\leq G \implies \langle H\rangle=H.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

On page $61$ of the book [Algebra](http://solmu.math.helsinki.fi/2010/algebra.pdf) by Tauno Metsänkylä, Marjatta Näätänen, it states

> $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{1\},\langle 1 \rangle =\{1\}. H\leq G \implies \langle H \rangle =H$

where $H \leq G$ means that H is the subgroup of G.

Now assumme $H=\emptyset$ so $\langle \emptyset \rangle = \emptyset \not = \{1\}$, contradiction. Please explain p.61 of the book that is the line in orange above.

Comment: The empty set is not a group, so we don't have $H \leq G $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $H \leq G$ means that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Your proposed counterexample fails because $\emptyset$ is not a subgroup of $G$ (it doesn't contain the identity element).

Comment: Correct. Can you explain $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{1\}$? Why not $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{\}$ or $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{0\}$? I cannot see where the very first statement follows from. +1 for explaining the implication.

Comment: Well, given a subset $S \subseteq G$, $\langle S\rangle$ can be defined as the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $S$. As every subgroup of $G$ contains $\emptyset$, the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $\emptyset$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$, which is the trivial group $\{1\}$. Note, this is just notation for the subgroup which contains the identity element of $G$ but nothing else. For any particular group $G$, the identity element may not be $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, can you check whether I have understood the statement in the title correctly -- I tried to elaborate about how I understand the issue in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1613222/5902.

Answer (score 3):

$\emptyset$ is not a subgroup of $G$, because it is not a group. Because $\langle X\rangle$ is **by definition**

> The smallest subgroup of $H$ that includes $X$

then if $X=\emptyset$, it is equal to $\{1\}$

Comment: Can you explain the implication *"if $X=\emptyset$, it is equal to $\{1\}$"*? Why not $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{\}$ or $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{0\}$?

Comment: @hhh Because $\{\}$ is not a subgroup, because, as I already said, **it is not a group**. And what is $0$ in the case of $\{0\}$? You only know about one element in $G$, and that is the *unit*. And you know that every subgroup of $G$ also has the same unit. And you know that $\{1\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, therefore it is the smallest subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{1\}$ follows from the definition of group that unit element 1 must be defined in the group, is this correct? So by this definition $\langle \emptyset \rangle$ is group only when $\langle\emptyset\rangle =\{1\}$, is this correct?

Comment: @hhh The sentence "$\langle \emptyset\rangle$ is group only when $\langle\emptyset\rangle = \{1\}$" is very clumsily written. The equality $\langle\emptyset\rangle = \{1\}$ is true **because** $\langle\emptyset\rangle$ is, by definition, a group.

Answer (score 0):

> $\langle \emptyset \rangle=\{1\},\langle 1 \rangle=\{1\}. H\leq G \implies \langle H\rangle=H.$

**Examples.**

$G=\mathbb R^*$ without zero. (G,*) is multiplicative group.

1. If you have $\langle \emptyset \rangle =\{\}=\emptyset$, then this $\emptyset$ cannot be a group because no unit element, failing the definition of the group so the implication false with this.
2. $H=0$. $\langle 0\rangle =\langle \emptyset\rangle=\{1\}$
3. $H=1$. $\langle 1\rangle =\{1\}$.
4. $H=6$. $\langle 6\rangle \not =\langle 2,3\rangle$ because $2\not\in\langle 6\rangle$ while $2\in\langle 2,3\rangle$.
5. $H=2$. $\langle 2\rangle =\{2^n\quad |\quad n\in\mathbb Z\}$. This is when $G=\mathbb Q^*$ because $0$ has no multiplicative inverse. This does not mean that the exponent cannot be zero i.e. the identity element $1\in\langle 2\rangle.$

**Exponents must be integers (not real numbers)**

1. $H=2$. When $G=\mathbb R^*$, $\langle 2\rangle = \{2^n\quad |\quad n\in\mathbb R\}.$ Wrong, the exponents must be integers.
2. $H=2$. When $G=\mathbb R^*$, $\langle 2\rangle = \{2^n \quad | \quad n\in\mathbb Z\}$.
3. $H=3$. $\langle 3\rangle =\{3^n\}$, $n\in\mathbb R$. Wrong, exponents cannot be real numbers.
4. $H=4$. $\langle 4\rangle =\langle 2\rangle$ because $\langle k\rangle,k\in\mathbb R^*$ consisting of all multiplies having the factors and their inverses. Wrong exponents cannot be real numbers.
5. $H=5$. $\langle 5\rangle =\{5^n\}, n\in\mathbb R$. Wrong because exponents must be integers.

**$\langle a\rangle$ is not defined here with sets of sets**

1. What is $\langle \{1\}\rangle$?  $\langle \{1\}\rangle =\{\{1\}\}$? $\{\{k\}\}$ is not a number so undefined? Sets of sets not addressed here.
2. Does the statement "$\langle \emptyset \rangle=\{1\},\langle 1 \rangle=\{1\}. H\leq G \implies \langle H\rangle=H.$" work with sets having sets like $\{\{\{1\}\}\}$? No.

**Further questions**

1. [Multiplicative group $(\mathbb R^*, ×)$ is group but $(\mathbb R, ×)$ is not group, why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613351/multiplicative-group-mathbb-r-is-group-but-mathbb-r-is-not-gro) where the question is also on additive groups: $(\mathbb R, +)$ is group but $(\mathbb R^*, +)$ is not group.

Comment: All of your examples are wrong. Furthermore, you need to specify what the group $G$ is before you can determine what $\langle x\rangle$ is for any $x \in G$ which is not the identity. For any group $G$, if we denote its identity element by $1$, then $\langle 1\rangle = \{1\}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese updated and specified the group G as multiplicative group $(G,*)$ such that $G=\mathbb R^*$ (without zero). Now better?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is not a group under multiplication, it is a group under addition.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese correct updated it to $R^*$ without zero.

Comment: In this example, for $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$, $a \neq \pm 1$, $\langle a\rangle$ is infinite; in particular $\langle a\rangle= \{a^k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Whereas $\langle 1\rangle = \{1\}$ and $\langle -1\rangle = \{1, -1\}$. You wrote $\langle 6\rangle = \langle 2, 3\rangle$ - this is false as $2 \in \langle 2, 3\rangle$ but $2 \not\in \langle 6\rangle$.

Comment: Is this correct $\langle 4\rangle =\langle 2\rangle$ in the group $(\mathbb R^*,*)$  (no zero in $\mathbb R^*$)?. Because $4^{\frac 1 2}=2$ and $G=\mathbb R^*$, $2\in \langle 4\rangle$, correct?

Comment: No it is not. Note that $2 \in \langle 2\rangle$ but $2 \not\in \langle 4\rangle$.

Comment: But $4^{0.5}=2$ so $2\in \langle 4\rangle$? Notice that $G=\mathbb R^*$, not $\mathbb Z$. The multiplicative group $(G,*)$ where $G=\mathbb R^*$.

Comment: I am aware of that, but $\langle 4\rangle = \{4^k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ (the exponent has to be an integer).

Comment: I have still one misunderstanding: can $\langle k\rangle$ be defined with additive operation? Or is it only defined such that $\langle S \rangle =\{a_1 a_2\dots a_m\quad |\quad a_i\in S \quad\forall i;\quad m\geq 0\}$ for finite group G? I feel the answer is no i.e. the $\langle a\rangle$ is defined to analyse multiples, not $a_1+a_2+...+a_n$.

Comment: For any group $G$, regardless of what the binary operation is, and any element $g \in G$, $\langle g\rangle$ is a well-defined subgroup, called the subgroup generated by $g$. In the particular case of multiplication on $\mathbb{R}^*$, $\langle g\rangle = \{g^k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. In the particular case of addition on $\mathbb{R}$, $\langle g\rangle = \{kg \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. If you still don't understand this concept, please ask a new question.