# Multiplicative group $(\mathbb R^*, ×)$ is group but $(\mathbb R, ×)$ is not group, why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

*$\mathbb R^*$ refers to $\mathbb R$ without zero.*

Please explain the statement *"$\mathbb R$  is not a group under multiplication, it is a group under addition."* in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613171/explain-langle-emptyset-rangle-1-langle-1-rangle-1-h-leq-g-impli#comment3288379_1613222). Basically:

1. Why is multiplicative group $(\mathbb R^*, ×)$ a group?
2. Why is $(\mathbb R, ×)$ not group?
3. Why are $(\mathbb R^*, +)$ and $(\mathbb R, +)$ groups?

Comment: 2. $0$ has no multiplicative inverse. 3. In $(\mathbb R^*,+)$ is no neutral element.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ can't be a multiplicative group because $0$ has no inverse (you can't solve "$0x=1$"). Write down the conditions that must be satisfied for the set with the operation to be a group. Show that each of them is satisfied. You will then have answered your own questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(\mathbb{R}^*, \times)$ is a group, since

- It has a neutral element $1$
- It has inverses $1\over x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^*$
- The operation is associative

$(\mathbb{R}, \times)$ is **not** a group, because $0$ has no multiplicative inverse.

$(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is a group, since

- It has a neutral element $0$
- It has inverses $-x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- The operation is associative

$(\mathbb{R}^*, +)$ is **not** a group, since it is not closed under operation: $x+(-x)=0 \not \in \mathbb{R}^*$

Comment: @Travis They are not. But $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^+, \times)$ are isomorphic, where the latter includes only positive numbers. And $(\mathbb{R}^*, \times) \cong (\mathbb{R}^+, \times)\times C_2$, where $C_2$ is cyclic of order 2.

Comment: Oops, you're right, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Something is a *group* if it satisfies the *group axioms* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition). So, for instance, $(\mathbb{R}, *)$ is not a group because one of the group axioms is the existence of inverses, and $0$ has no multiplicative inverse. Similarly, your (3) is partly wrong: $(\mathbb{R}^*, +)$ is not a group because (a) it is not closed under the operation $+$, and (b) does not have an identity for the operation $+$.

Showing that something is a group is slightly more complicated than showing that something *isn't* a group, since in the latter case you just have to exhibit a single counterexample; but looking at the group axioms, do you see how to verify them for the remaining examples?

Answer (score 2):

$(\mathbb{R},*)$ is not a group because there does not exist a multiplicative inverse for $0$. If you remove $0$, the problem is solved. Thus, $(\mathbb{R}^*,*)$ is a group. (I do not want to show the group axioms here). With addition, we do not have this problem since $0$ is inverse to itself under addition.