# Why ignore zero in multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra

As, set of real numbers make group under multiplication but why we ignore zero in multiplicative groups.We can use zero as a counter example to disproof that its inverse doesn't lie in the set??

Comment: Are you sure that $(\mathbb R,×)$ is a group? Or $(\mathbb R^{*},×)$ is a group?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613351/multiplicative-group-mathbb-r-×-is-group-but-mathbb-r-×-is-not-gro?rq=1) for a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Zero has no multiplicative inverse. So $\mathbb{R}$ is **not** a group with respect to multiplication. We must omit zero to make it a group.